# Resume training faster-rccn model from the last step after the interrupted session on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, faster-rcnn

Used faster-rcnn to train my model on Google Colab. However, due to the GPU time limit, my model stopped training at 7000 steps out of 10,000 steps.

I used the following code to train the model

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2 --pipeline_config_path=models/my_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2/pipeline.config
```

How can I resume training my model from the last step (i.e. 7000)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out after following [this](https://medium.com/@afetulhak/how-to-resume-restart-training-faster-rcnn-using-tensor-flow-object-detection-api-d05164f329b) tutorial. So to resume the training, I changed the directory location for fine_tune_checkpoint from the pre-trained model directory (i.e. pretrained_mode/checkpoint/ckpt-0) to my model training directory location where model checkpoints are saved (i.e. /my_training_model/ckpt-#). ***Replace # with the number of the last ckpt e.g. ckpt-9***

Then I rerun the following command to resume the training:

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2 --pipeline_config_path=models/my_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2/pipeline.config
```